# Delete a row after a delete on a different table?

Tags: mysql, triggers, delete-row

I have two tables.

`Table_A` holds a student's ID (PK) and their name.
`Table_B` holds a student's ID (PK) (FK from Table_A) and their address.

I want to create a trigger that deletes the student from `Table_A` if they were deleted from `Table_B`.

What I have so far:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER del_student
    AFTER DELETE ON Table_B
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE Table_B
        FROM Table_A, Table_B
        WHERE Table_A.ID = Table_B.ID;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Currently this does not work as intended. How would I point to the recently deleted row from `Table_B` so that it would delete the correct row from `Table_A`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: the delete statement could be as `delete from Table_A where ID = old.ID`

Comment: Why a trigger, as opposed to a cascade, or just a single delete statement

Comment: The above code is a very simple example of a bigger schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits go to Abhik Chakraborty in the comments above.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER del_student
    AFTER DELETE ON Table_B
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Table_A
        WHERE old.ID = Table_A.ID;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```